# RedirectToAction causing empty cookie to be set ahead of cookie with values, which results in "lost" cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, redirect, httpcookie

I am using a cookie and if the cookie is set, it forwards the user to signin, else it shows them an error page (unauthorized).  The cookie is being set correctly, and if I navigate to any page by typing it in the address bar, it works just fine.  However, when I use RedirectToAction or FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLogin the cookie is not available, which is causing an infinite loop in redirection.

Home - If user has cookie, go to signin, if not show home page.

Signin - If user has cookie, show page, else redirect to home

My redirection is handled through an attribute.

```
public sealed class RequireBillerAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        IUserSession session = ServiceLocator.Locate<IUserSession>();

        if (session.BillerId == 0)
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/");
    }
}
```

My Home action looks like this

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //if the user is signed in, send them to their account page.  They don't need to see the front page
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {          
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
        }

        //users with their cookie set should sign in
        if (session.BillerId != 0)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "SignIn");

        return View();
    }
```

And my signin action looks like this

```
    [RequireBiller]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        SignInModel model = BuildSignInModel();

        return View(model);
    }
```

Now, when I hit mysite.com/ the redirect causes an infinite loop.  In debugging, the attribute cannot find the value from the cookie. The cookie is actually blank in the request.  When I type mysite.com/signin everything works peachy.  Any ideas?

**EDIT**

As suggested, I ran fiddler.  Here's what the requests look like

```
#   Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
1   302 HTTP    localhost:27412 /   124 private     text/html; charset=utf-8    chrome:6008         
2   302 HTTP    localhost:27412 /SignIn 118 private     text/html; charset=utf-8    chrome:6008         
3   302 HTTP    localhost:27412 /   124 private     text/html; charset=utf-8    chrome:6008         
4   302 HTTP    localhost:27412 /SignIn 118 private     text/html; charset=utf-8    chrome:6008
```

And here is the cookie information

First

> __RequestVerificationToken_Lw__=NNu8v2oTMX2YKQOW+JRN1LQRYPhlmPszQa8Rs1KrQp1pPxWmQO8GG7eRrzbhFZF38p05ckuLHAK3QaTIlxeFJ6POTX1woXRx/ahApLpF529inJO9mj3jSnoHqG6fthzJpoLYQL61NOCCUO2wwzLmQg==;
>   4%40f0nkyBbqcTD4g9yl1J8KDNcWdqRpixrEoHLuMP2Lc*=P%2ffJD5CdLO0pCGU6GntaPw**=P6QAytlDVUrkQn84c9vDVg**

Second

> 4%40f0nkyBbqcTD4g9yl1J8KDNcWdqRpixrEoHLuMP2Lc*=;
>   __RequestVerificationToken_Lw__=NNu8v2oTMX2YKQOW+JRN1LQRYPhlmPszQa8Rs1KrQp1pPxWmQO8GG7eRrzbhFZF38p05ckuLHAK3QaTIlxeFJ6POTX1woXRx/ahApLpF529inJO9mj3jSnoHqG6fthzJpoLYQL61NOCCUO2wwzLmQg==;
>   4%40f0nkyBbqcTD4g9yl1J8KDNcWdqRpixrEoHLuMP2Lc*=P%2ffJD5CdLO0pCGU6GntaPw**=P6QAytlDVUrkQn84c9vDVg**

Third

> __RequestVerificationToken_Lw__=NNu8v2oTMX2YKQOW+JRN1LQRYPhlmPszQa8Rs1KrQp1pPxWmQO8GG7eRrzbhFZF38p05ckuLHAK3QaTIlxeFJ6POTX1woXRx/ahApLpF529inJO9mj3jSnoHqG6fthzJpoLYQL61NOCCUO2wwzLmQg==;
>   4%40f0nkyBbqcTD4g9yl1J8KDNcWdqRpixrEoHLuMP2Lc*=P%2ffJD5CdLO0pCGU6GntaPw**=P6QAytlDVUrkQn84c9vDVg**

Fourth

> 4%40f0nkyBbqcTD4g9yl1J8KDNcWdqRpixrEoHLuMP2Lc*=;
>   __RequestVerificationToken_Lw__=NNu8v2oTMX2YKQOW+JRN1LQRYPhlmPszQa8Rs1KrQp1pPxWmQO8GG7eRrzbhFZF38p05ckuLHAK3QaTIlxeFJ6POTX1woXRx/ahApLpF529inJO9mj3jSnoHqG6fthzJpoLYQL61NOCCUO2wwzLmQg==;
>   4%40f0nkyBbqcTD4g9yl1J8KDNcWdqRpixrEoHLuMP2Lc*=P%2ffJD5CdLO0pCGU6GntaPw**=P6QAytlDVUrkQn84c9vDVg**

And here's what it looks like when I type in /signin into the address bar

> __RequestVerificationToken_Lw__=NNu8v2oTMX2YKQOW+JRN1LQRYPhlmPszQa8Rs1KrQp1pPxWmQO8GG7eRrzbhFZF38p05ckuLHAK3QaTIlxeFJ6POTX1woXRx/ahApLpF529inJO9mj3jSnoHqG6fthzJpoLYQL61NOCCUO2wwzLmQg==;
>   4%40f0nkyBbqcTD4g9yl1J8KDNcWdqRpixrEoHLuMP2Lc*=P%2ffJD5CdLO0pCGU6GntaPw**=P6QAytlDVUrkQn84c9vDVg**

Yes, my cookies are encrypted.  The cookiename is "4%40f0nkyBbqcTD4g9yl1J8KDNcWdqRpixrEoHLuMP2Lc*" It seems to me the redirect is appending a new empty cookie in there.  WHY?  I'm not sure.

**ADDITIONAL**
After debugging, I have found that indeed there are 3 cookies in the Request.  The first is the empty cookie, which is returned by default when using the name.  The third cookie in the collection has the values set.  Why it is appending this cookie into the request is a mystery.  I can probably work around this by picking the cookie that has a value over the other one, but I'd rather fix the root issue, whatever it is, that is happening only on the signin page.

Comment: Because it does! Can you use Server.Transfer?

Comment: Is there a reason to use a cookie for this? There's a perfectly workable solution built-in that you should use instead. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs

Comment: no, and now, all of a sudden, without any change to the cookie code, my cookie is no longer setting, period.  This is frustrating.

Comment: @rboarman - I am using the formsauth cookie for signin.  This cookie is for tracking the user.  You have to come in from a valid outside source through a redirection url to get the cookie set, which then allows you to sign in.

Comment: Okay, I would then use Fiddler to see what requests are going on and to look at the cookie itself.

Comment: okay, this is weird.  I changed my redirection to send the user to the register page using RedirectToAction and it works fine.  There is something about redirecting to the signin page that is causing the cookie to drop.  It also drops if I click a link to sign in.

Comment: I tried changing the default for forms auth off the signin page and the cookie still drops.  I'll keep investigating.

Comment: Okay, it's not anything in the content of the signin page. The controller looks like all the others.  Both have the requirebiller attribute.  I don't get what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what's happening is that RedirectToAction is doing a Response.Redirect() which is terminating the processing of the request and not allowing the cookie to be set. Sounds like a similar problem to what is documented here for session:

http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2004/08/03/207486.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, page does not exist

Comment: Archived page from web archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20140304013447/http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2004/08/03/207486.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had a cookie that was not being set properly after calling RedirectToAction(). I ended up utilizing TempData[] as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3624353/1265197

Here is my code. The account string was retrieved via a Query String on the url named 'account':

```
public ActionResult OriginatingAction(string account)
{
    //Some other code
    TempData["data"] = account; 

    return RedirectToAction("RedirectAction");
}
```

I could then use TempData["data"] to set the cookie in the action that I redirected to:

```
public ActionResult RedirectAction()
{
    if(TempData["data"] != null)
    {
        HttpCookie dataCookie = new HttpCookie("dataCookie");
        dataCookie.Values.Add("account", TempData["data"] as string);
        dataCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12);
        Response.Cookies.Add(dataCookie);
    }

    return View();
}
```